# OSM2PGSQL for CentOS 6

Tags: centos, openstreetmap, postgis

I am trying to load the data from planet osm files to postgres database installed on CentOS server. Is there any available binary for CentOS which i can be used. I am not well conversant with C and C++ hence cannot build it from source. Need binary which i can use directly for loading data into postgres on CentOS.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a long and extensive [osm2pgsql wiki page](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql) in the OSM wiki which also explains how to [build it from source](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#From_source_.28generic.29). You don't need any C or C++ knowledge to build packages from source, basic Linux knowledge should be enough.